# How to convert multiple strings into json object in C#

Tags: c#

I have a for each loop and it will iterate n number of times. I need to convert string data into json object.

```
foreach(UserDetails details in data) 
{
    string firstname = details.firstname;
    string lastname = details.lastname;
}
```

My output should be like below.

```json
[
    {
        "firstname" : "abc",
        "lastname" : "xyz"
    },
    {
        "firstname" : "def",
        "lastname" : "uvw"
    },
    {
        "firstname" : "ghi",
        "lastname" : "rst"
    },
    ..........
    ..........
]
```

**I have tied below code**

```
string json = null;
foreach(UserDetails details in data) 
{
    string firstname = details.firstname;
    string lastname = details.lastname;
    var udata = new UData() 
    {
        FirstName = firstname, 
        LastName = lastname 
    };
    UData[] arr = new UData[] {udata};
    json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arr);
}
return json;
```

```
Public class UData
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}
```

But it is not working as expected, Could any one help on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: @David while your comment is generally good for educating new users, this question was pretty easy to ID the problem on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting `arr` and `json` in every iteration of your loop. You need to add elements to your array and convert the whole array to JSON.

Something like this should work:

```
List<UData> names = new List<UData>();
foreach (UserDetails details in data)
{
    var udata = new UData() { FirstName = details.firstname, LastName = details.lastname };
    names.Add(udata);
}

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(names);
```

Note, I've refactored the code a little for readability but some more refactoring could improve this further. Look into LINQ, specifically the `.Select` extension.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-8.0

Comment: Hi Tristan,
Thank you so much, it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the output you are getting is only the last item converted to JSON, and not a whole collection. That's because you're creating a new collection of `UData` each loop, putting just the one object in it, and then serializing it. See the comment below.

```
string json = null;
foreach(UserDetails details in data) 
{
    string firstname = details.firstname;
    string lastname = details.lastname;
    var udata = new UData() 
    {
        FirstName = firstname, 
        LastName = lastname 
    };
    UData[] arr = new UData[] {udata};
    json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arr); // <--- Here's the problem
}
return json;
```

Here's the proper way to do this:

```
UData[] arr = new UData[]{};
foreach(UserDetails details in data) 
{
    string firstname = details.firstname;
    string lastname = details.lastname;
    var udata = new UData() 
    {
        FirstName = firstname, 
        LastName = lastname 
    };
    arr.Add(udata);
}
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arr);
```

This will give you a collection of all of your `UData` objects you're creating in your loop, and then you serialize the *entire* collection. That is the easiest way to get a valid JSON object containing your data.

Comment: Hi Logarr,
Thank you so much, it is working fine.